# AngularJS - set Nav Bar

Tags: angularjs

I'm doing a single page application using AngularJS. On my index.html I'm using an ng-view direction to show the header section. The navigation section is defined as a ul element with a bunch of li elements that represents navigation links. I have a ng-class on each li element that needs to set the class to active. Based on my code, it does, but it doesn't appear on the page until after I click on the page. Provided is my code, please help. Thank you in advance

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 1 Template</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/isotope.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="appMod">

    <!-- Start: Header -->
    <div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
    <!-- End: Header -->
    <!-- Start: Content -->
    <div ng-view></div>
    <!-- End: Content -->
    <!-- Start: Footer -->
    <div ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></div>
    <!-- End: Footer -->


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Vendor: Angular, followed by our custom Javascripts -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <!-- parent angular module and controller that supports SPA (Single Page Application) -->
  <script src="app/appMod.js"></script>
  <script src="templates/TemplateCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="app/home/HomeCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="app/blog/BlogCtrl.js"></script>
  <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

templates/header.html

```
<header >
<div class="main-menu" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" data-0="line-height:90px;" data-300="line-height:50px;">          Hidayah
        </a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-controller="TemplateHeadCtrl">
              <li  ng-repeat="NavLink in NavLinks"  ng-class="IsSelected(NavLink)">
                <a href="{{NavLink.LinkURL}}" ng-click="SetMaster(NavLink)">{{NavLink.LinkTitle}}</a>
              </li>
              <!-- <li id='liHome' class="active"></li>
              <li id='liPortfolio'><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
              <li id='liBlog'><a href="#/Blog">Blog</a></li>
              <li id='liContact'><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>-->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

templates/TemplateCtrl.js

```
app.controller("TemplateHeadCtrl", ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){

   $scope.NavLinks = [
     {
       "LinkTitle": "Home",
       "LinkURL": "#/",
       "LinkID": "liHome"
     },
     {
       "LinkTitle": "Portfolio",
       "LinkURL": "#Portfolio",
       "LinkID": "liPortfolio"
     },
     {
       "LinkTitle": "Blog",
       "LinkURL": "#Blog",
       "LinkID": "liBlog"
     },
     {
       "LinkTitle": "Contact",
       "LinkURL": "#Contact",
       "LinkID": "liContact"
     },

     {
       "LinkTitle": "Contact1",
       "LinkURL": "#Contact1",
       "LinkID": "liContact1"
     }
   ];
  /*
   $scope.NavLinks = function () {
      alert("here")
       return $http.get('/NavLinks.json').then(function (response) {
           alert("here")
           return  response.data;
       }).catch(function (fallback) {
           alert("Oops an error has occured. ")
       });
   };*/
   $scope.SetMaster = function(section){
     $scope.SelectedSection = section;

   };
   $scope.IsSelected = function(section){

      return $scope.SelectedSection === section? 'active': '';
   };

}]);
```

Also for some reason the $scope.NavLinks function does not work either. I have it commented it out in my code. The NavLinks.json is located under the same folder of TemplateCtrl.js

```
$scope.NavLinks = function () {
      alert("here")
       return $http.get('/NavLinks.json').then(function (response) {
           alert("here")
           return  response.data;
       }).catch(function (fallback) {
           alert("Oops an error has occured. ")
       });
   };
```

Comment: Could you give us an example on jsfiddle or plunkr please ?

Comment: Is there a problem reading the code listed above?

Comment: I can't see a problem in your code, i need to test it.

Comment: For your second question, you should understand what promises are, see this link: http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/

Comment: @Aliz Here's a link to the solution from drop box. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wiasso7ezetmbz1/Hidayah.zip?dl=0. When I added the solution to plunker everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Make change in 'templates/header.html' like this:

```
<li  ng-repeat="NavLink in NavLinks"  ng-class="{active : IsSelected(NavLink)}">
    <a href="{{NavLink.LinkURL}}" ng-click="SetMaster(NavLink)">{{NavLink.LinkTitle}}</a>
</li>
```

And in 'templates/TemplateCtrl.js':

```
$scope.IsSelected = function(section){
    return $scope.SelectedSection.LinkID == section.LinkID;
};
```